# Group by variable integer range using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm trying to group a set of data based on the range of an integer, by the range does not increase at a fixed interval.

e.g. I have

Item ID     Price 
1                    10 
2                   30 
3                   50 
4                  120

I would like to group the items with price 0 - 10, 11 - 100, and 100-500. So that item 1 is in group A, item 2,3, in group B, item 4 in group C.

The closest I can come up is
from items
group items by (items.price / 10 )

then join the groups together to get the different ranges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Parameterizing the list of range ceilings...

```
var ceilings = new[] { 10, 100, 500 };
var groupings = items.GroupBy(item => ceilings.First(ceiling => ceiling >= item));
```

Comment: +1 because this is naturally extensible for the most general case, since the list of ceilings can itself be dynamically generated via `Enumerable.Range().Select()`

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this?

```
var data = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Price = 2 },
    new { Id = 1, Price = 10 },
    new { Id = 2, Price = 30 },
    new { Id = 3, Price = 50 },
    new { Id = 4, Price = 120 },
    new { Id = 5, Price = 200 },
    new { Id = 6, Price = 1024 },
};

var ranges = new[] { 10, 50, 100, 500 };

var grouped = data.GroupBy( x => ranges.FirstOrDefault( r => r > x.Price ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like (untested):

```
item.Price <= 10 ? "A" :
     (item.Price <= 100 ? "B" : (item.Price <= 500 ? "C" : "X"))
```

(and group by this)

If this is LINQ-to-Objects, you could also do this in a static utility function (`GetBand(i)` or similar); or with LINQ-to-SQL you could do the same with a scalar-UDF mapped to the data-context.

Answer (score -1):

You could select the ints in different sets with Linq.

Something like:

```
 var newList = theList.Where(i => i < 30 && i >10);
```

This would get you all of th eints from a certain interval.