# Linq - Grouping by range results in "sub-query returns more than one row"

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, dotconnect

I am using the following LINQ to group by a variable range ([as per question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375997/group-by-variable-integer-range-using-linq))

```
 var ranges = new List<decimal> { 5m, 10m, 20m };

 var grouped = entities.PointTransaction.Where( x => x.UserInfo.College == collegeID 
                  && x.Amount < 0)
                 .GroupBy( x=> ranges.FirstOrDefault( r => r >= Math.Abs( (decimal) x.Amount) )
                  ).ToList();
```

However, I will get the error:

```
single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

When none of the rows match any of the ranges ( say, the values are all less than 5), the query will work.

I am using DevArt Dotconnect for Oracle, Entity Framework 4

Comment: How do I check the generated sql?

Comment: Extrakun, we have answered you at our forum: http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22093